# How to call getElementById() on multiple ids

Tags: javascript

Previously I made an `onchange` input, there are several inputs that have the same thing called by id. How do I call multiple
ids in one line of code? I tried to write it like this but failed:

```js
   
function minmax() {
  const inp_field = document.querySelectorAll("#input1, #input2, #input3, #input4");

  let val = parseFloat(inp_field.value),
      min = parseFloat(inp_field.min),
      max = parseFloat(inp_field.max);

  if (val < min) {
      inp_field.value = min;
  } else if (val > max) {
      inp_field.value = max;
  } else {
      inp_field.value = val;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="0.01" max="94.99">
<input id="input2" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="0.1" max="99.99">
<input id="input3" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="5" max="25">
<input id="input4" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: Your query is fine, but you can't access individual attrributes direclty on the returned NodeList. You'll need to iterate over the array-like.

Comment: You don't need to update all the inputs onchange= of one of them - change to `onchange="minmax(this)"` and your `function minmax(inp_field)` then remove the `querySelectorAll`

Comment: **Use classes or name - and attribute selector..** If you go to your HTML and add another INPUT Element, you're not supposed to go to JS and add another ID to yout selectors string... Also, stop using inline `on*` handlers.

Comment: I don't think those `min`/`max` attributes work on a `type="text"` Have you tried the proper HTML: `<input` **type="number"** `min='0' max='100'>`

Comment: i like trying this and it works fine. Thanks, this is a great solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you really need all that... try this and see if it serves your need.

```js
function minmax(inp_field) {

    let val = parseFloat(inp_field.value),
    min = parseFloat(inp_field.min),
    max = parseFloat(inp_field.max);

    //below we call a function that checks if the value contains any scientific/engineering notation
    val = decimalCount(val)

    if (val < min) {
        inp_field.value = inp_field.min;
    } else if (val > max) {
        inp_field.value = inp_field.max;
    } else {
        inp_field.value = val;
    }
}

function decimalCount(val){
    let valStr = val.toString(); //convert float to string
    //check if the value include e-... example 1e-7
    if(valStr.includes('e-')){
        //get the value before the scietific notation
        let beforeE = valStr.substr(0,valStr.indexOf('e'));
        //the following removes a comma. example 0.000000017 == 1.7e-7
        beforeE = beforeE.replace('.','')
        //get the number of zeros after the scientific notation
        let decimalPlace = valStr.substr((valStr.indexOf('-') + 1)) - 1
        //we set a variable for the zeros after the .
        let zeros = '.';
        //assign the zeros to appear after the .
        for(let i=0;i<decimalPlace;i++){
            zeros += 0;
        }
        //concatenate the results and return the value for display
        return 0 + zeros + beforeE;
    }else{
        //else, we return the min/max as it is
        return val;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" onchange="minmax(this)" min="0.01" max="94.99">
<input id="input2" type="text" onchange="minmax(this)" min="0.00000001" max="99.99">
<input id="input3" type="text" onchange="minmax(this)" min="5" max="25">
<input id="input4" type="text" onchange="minmax(this)" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: Inline on* handlers are to be avoided. Also, there's no need to set a value to it's unchanged value.

Comment: Exactly. I just did that to maintain context since the OP seems like a newbie. He could've easliy set an event listener for the input fields and handle each accordingly.

Comment: this is very clear to, but if for example changing the input min=0.00000001, it will change to "1e-8", what is the solution to leave it at "0.00000001"

Comment: It'll assign the value as '0.00000001'. I've updated the code and changed `#input2` min value to `0.00000001` and tested it. It returns the value without the scientic notation. Try it out and let me know if it suits your need

Comment: @Relcode I am very grateful. this is exactly what i need, but when i try to fill the value with 0.00000001, 0.00000002 and so on... it again changes to 1e-8, 2e-8... exactly what i need the input value is to stay with "0.00000001", " 0.00000002"....

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you mean. I have added an update and well that one is a bit messy. I've created a function that checks for scientific notation and try to restore the number to its true value if a notation is identified. You can spend some time going through the code and see how it works and how you can make it better.

Run it and let me know how it goes...

Comment: You are amazing, Thank you so much for helping with this. everything went well, as needed

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to upvote and mark this as the accepted answer so that it can help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to update each input value based on its `min`/`max` attributes as it changes:

1. There's no real need for those ids. If you wanted to group them you could use a class instead, but here I'm just picking up the inputs by element name.
2. Remove the requirement for inline JS and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach listeners to each input.
3. You can use `this` (the context referring to the clicked element) in the function to make the code more concise.
4. You can remove `this.value = val` since the input value is already set.
5. Finally, while `max`/`min` aren't specified as attributes on a you can use with `type="text"` apparently you *can* still use them. But you may want to change to `type="number"`.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', minMax);
});

function minMax() {

  const val = parseFloat(this.value);
  const min = parseFloat(this.min);
  const max = parseFloat(this.max);

  if (val < min) this.value = min;
  if (val > max) this.value = max;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" min="0.01" max="94.99">
<input type="text" min="0.1" max="99.99">
<input type="text" min="5" max="25">
<input type="text" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: The author likely wants to keep the inputs in sync, which explains a collection-like jQuery approach in the first place.

Comment: How do you mean "in sync" @ViacheslavMoskalenko? Each input has its own min/max set of attributes. There's no point in changing all of them if you can simply update one at a time when it changes.

Comment: That's not an improvement @RokoC.Buljan - that calls the function on each keypress. For example if you type 3 in the third input it immediately sets its value to 5 when maybe you wanted to type 33, so now you've got to delete the value you just typed etc. `change` is much better for this example.

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko if he wanted them to be "in sync", then there's no logical reason in each input field having its own value or its own onchange function.

Comment: I realized that and removed my comment the next second after posting it ;) PS Instead of the two `if` statements: `this.value = Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max)`

Comment: this is very clear, but if for example changing the input min=0.00000001, it will change to "1e-8", what is the solution to leave it at "0.00000001"

Comment: Is this a likely use-case? [This may help](https://blog.davidjs.com/2018/07/convert-exponential-numbers-to-decimal-in-javascript/). @MaruliDavin

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to keep all the inputs in sync whenever one of them is changing, then a slight adjustment is required using `forEach`.
Keep in mind, however, that `querySelectorAll` produces a `NodeList`, not an `Array`:

```
 function minmax() {
  const inp_fields = document.querySelectorAll("#input1, #input2, #input3, #input4");

  inp_fields.forEach(inp_field => {
    let val = parseFloat(inp_field.value),
    min = parseFloat(inp_field.min),
    max = parseFloat(inp_field.max);

    if (val < min) {
        inp_field.value = min;
    } else if (val > max) {
        inp_field.value = max;
    } else {
        inp_field.value = val;
    }
  });
}
```

Just make sure to change your input fields type to `number` and set a proper default `value` (for example, `0`), because otherwise your calculations will yield to `NaN` being set to all the other fields upon modifying any of them.

Comment: If OP changes input1, then changes input2 - input1 hasn't changed when input2 is changed, so there's no need to re-validate input1.

Comment: input1 can change it's value (not to be confused with 'change' event) when input2 is changed by a user. I guess that's the authors initial intent - run through all the inputs upon changes in any of them and keep their values within [min, max] interval .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop.

```js
function minmax() {
  const inp_field_arr = ["input1", "input2", "input3", "input4"];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < inp_field_arr.length; i++) {
    inp_field = document.getElementById(inp_field_arr[i]);

    let val = parseFloat(Number(inp_field.value)),
        min = parseFloat(Number(inp_field.min)),
        max = parseFloat(Number(inp_field.max));

    if (val < min) {
        inp_field.value = min;
    } else if (val > max) {
        inp_field.value = max;
    } else {
        inp_field.value = val;
    }
 }
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="0.01" max="94.99">
<input id="input2" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="0.1" max="99.99">
<input id="input3" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="5" max="25">
<input id="input4" type="text" onchange="minmax()" min="1" max="10">
```

A more efficient way of doing this, though, would be to get the value in the onChange part. This can also fix some errors that may occur.

You can do this by removing the `let val`, `let min`, and `let max`, and instead using `onchange="minmax(parseFloat(this.value), parseFloat(this.min), parseFloat(this.max))"`, and making the function declaration `function minmax(val, min, max)`.

More information about:

for loop [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/for-loops-for-of-loops-and-for-in-loops-in-javascript) [DevDocs](https://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/for) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)

Number [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score -1):

like this ,ids are can change according your code ,like this, ids are can change according to your code,but logical is this

```js
const elements=document.qeuerySelectorAll('#id, #id2,#id3');
elements.foreEach(funcion(element){
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use `class`es, instead of element `id`s, when you are dealing with multiple elements. And is, also, a best practice.
Then you can use a function like `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: This is already stated in comments and in other answers. There's no need to partially create answers with partial improvements. Please take a look at the already posted ones before answering. This is more like a comment to OP's question.